# I don't understand how python uwsgi is multi-processed

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, uwsgi

I don't understand that when running with uwsgi multi-process, the `id()` value of the object generated by each thread is the same, and the `threading.get_ident()` value of each process is the same.

I ran uwsgi with flask app in 4 processes with `--proces 4` option.

```
16:47:09,709|object initiating... obj_id : 139755460182224, pid : 9833, threading.get_ident : 139756071208704|
16:47:09,975|object initiating... obj_id : 139755459113168, pid : 9835, threading.get_ident : 139756071208704|
16:47:09,982|object initiating... obj_id : 139755459113168, pid : 9832, threading.get_ident : 139756071208704|
16:47:10,022|object initiating... obj_id : 139755459113168, pid : 9834, threading.get_ident : 139756071208704|
```

However, I do not understand that the `id()` values of the objects generated by each process are the same, nor do I understand that the `threading.get_ident()` value is the same.

I thought the `id` value based on the memory address of the object could not be the same because the memory is not shared between processes, but I don't understand that the id value is the same.

(Of course, I know it can be the same because it's a relative memory address, not an absolute memory address, but I don't understand the same thing every time.)

Also, if the process is different, of course the thread will be different, but I don't understand that the thread identifier value, `threading.get_ident()`, has the same result value.

How do I understand uwsgi's multiprocessing?

---

`temp.py` file that defines the class

```py
import os
import threading
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s|%(levelname)s|object|%(message)s|")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)


class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        logger.info(f" object initiating... obj_id : {id(self)} pid : {os.getpid()} thread_id : {threading.get_ident()}")
```

Create object A from the flask `hello` file

```py
import logging
from flask import Flask
from temp import A

app = Flask(__name__)

a = A()

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

the wsgi.py

```
from hello import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

my command

`~/.virtualenvs/testflask/bin/uwsgi --http :5004 --module wsgi:app --logto ./log.log --processes 4 --enable-threads --single-interpreter --master --lazy-apps`

Comment: Show us the code that generated the output.

Comment: @KlausD. I have added that code to the question.

Comment: Your relevant code line does not run on imports. How would it be executed by the WSGI server? Show us the real code!

Comment: @KlausD. Ok this is real code

Comment: You are creating the instance at import time, before the WSGI server forks the worker processes off. Try it inside the `hello` function to get a different result.

Comment: @KlausD. But since I gave uwsgi the `lazy-apps` option, the app loads from each worker. I don't understand your saying that it will be imported before the fork.